# Are several equality operators okay to use in mathematics?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

For example, is it okay to say:

$x=y=z=1$ if $x,y,z$ all equal $1$?

Comment: Yup, es cool man

Comment: $x = y = 1$ means that $x$ is the same as $y$ and $y$ is $1$. That means the same as saying that $x$ and $y$ are both $1$.

Comment: Yes. Just don't wrote $a\neq b\neq c$ if you mean all three are different - that's a serious abuse of notation.

Comment: Perfectly fine. Technically, this means $$x=y \textrm{ and } y=z \textrm{ and } z=1$$ from which the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; this is commonly used and widely accepted notation.

Comment: Why did you make it community wiki?

Comment: @Shahar so that there is no hesitation in upvoting it, so that the question will be removed from the unanswered queue.

Comment: Wait, what does community wiki do?

Comment: @Shahar In a nutshell: community wiki questions don't "belong" to any user, but to the site as a whole.  In particular, votes on this question do not affect my reputation, and drastic changes to this post change the name that appears in the bottom-right.  I find this   useful for questions with particularly easy answers where no credit is deserved.

Comment: That wasn't a nutshell, that was an entire nut.